# What is the equivalent API of tf.contrib.factorization.KMeans in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cluster-analysis, k-means

In Tensorflow 1.13.1 the clustering models can be built using **KMeans** alogithm using `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeans` but after upgrading to TensorFlow 2.0, I'm finding it difficult to locate a suitable API for building a clustering model. I found an estimator API for K-Means  `tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans`. However, it is not as developer friendly as the former one. I need to implement a clustering model using TensorFlow but not sure which API would be a right fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old KMeans API was refactored to follow the Estimator API and the `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeans` was deprecated even before moving to Tensorflow 2.0. The "estimator" way of doing k-means is the same in both [1.15](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/experimental/KMeans) and [2.x](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/experimental/KMeans).

If you are looking for more "friendly" way, to my knowledge you are left with e.g. [scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). Estimators are not going away anytime soon, so familiarising with them isn't a bad idea (though there's a learning curve).